# Pass arguments to Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular App, where in the landing page is index.html, this app is accessed from other application and I need to pass arguments into app to be used

Like

http://localhost:4200/myapp/index.html?name=John&role=merchant

where name and role are arguments , angular needs to ready them and store in header object to be used accross the application.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

This may help for you:

```
name:string;
role:string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.name= params['name']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
           this.role= params['role'];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code give you current Url using array functions you can get name and role:-

```
let currentUrl = this.router.url;
```

You can append header as below:-

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('name', this.name);
headers.append('role', this.role);
```